# $ 1 + \sqrt{1 - \sqrt{x^4-x^2}} = x$ can be written in the form $\frac{a}{b}$, find $a+b$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The solution to the equation 
$$1 + \sqrt{1 - \sqrt{x^4-x^2}} = x$$
 can be written in the form $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a$ and $b$ are coprime positive integers. Find $a+b$.

Comment: This is a live problem on brilliant.org, please close this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

First isolate the square root on one side:

$$\sqrt{1-\sqrt{x^4-x^2}}=x-1\;.$$

Now square:

$$1-\sqrt{x^4-x^2}=(x-1)^2=x^2-2x+1\;.$$

Then $-\sqrt{x^4-x^2}=x^2-2x$, $\sqrt{x^4-x^2}=2x-x^2$, and $x^4-x^2=(2x-x^2)^2=x^4-4x^3+4x^2$. Simplification yields the equation $4x^3-5x^2=0$, or $x^2(4x-5)=0$. This is easy to solve. Be careful, though: you need to check each solution back in the original equation, because the squaring steps may have introduced extraneous solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the question is not a live problem anymore. What you can do to solve this is just solving for $x$. So assume $x$ is a solution, then $\sqrt{1-\sqrt{x^4-x^2}}=x-1$, so $1-\sqrt{x^4-x^2}=(x-1)^2$. Continuing like this you will get to $-4x^3+5x^2=0$. This has two solutions, but one of the solutions is not a solution to the original equation, an excellent example that squaring will in general not yield to an equivalent equation.

Comment: Have you been waiting these months just to answer this question?

Comment: @oldrinb No, I'm camping the unanswered questions (see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4437/could-chatrooms-serve-as-noticeboards/9868#9868 for more information) and this question was shown as unanswered because Brian's answer was deleted, I suppose for the live problem reason.